# changes in velocity template to reflect without server restart

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, velocity

Is there any way to make the changes made in vm file to reflect automatically without restarting the server everytime. I am in development phase right now and i have quite a few changes to be done. I am new to velocity template and hence it will be highly helpful If someone could suggest a way for the same. I tried using the following properties but it doesn't work.I am using tomcat server.

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
 <property name="velocityProperties">
        <value> 
            resource.loader=class            
           class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
            velocimacro.library.autoreload=true
            class.resource.loader.cache=false
            velocimacro.permissions.allow.inline.to.replace.global=true
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct, you are trying to hot deploy your velocity template (vm extension) on your server.
If we refer at the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-velocity), you should rather go for the "file" oriented properties.

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
 <property name="velocityProperties">
        <value> 
            resource.loader=file            
            file.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader
            velocimacro.library.autoreload=true
            file.resource.loader.cache=true
            file.resource.loader.path=/WEB-INF/views
            velocimacro.permissions.allow.inline.to.replace.global=true
            file.resource.loader.modificationCheckInterval=2
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Make sure that your views path is correct (`file.resource.loader.path`). I added `file.resource.loader.modificationCheckInterval` because as you are caching the templates, you should give the number of seconds between two checks.

Comment: in this way,I couldn't load template files,since it couldn't find root path.Because I use velocity to render some html section,just not take velocity as views render engine.So I post my way here...

Answer (score 0):

You can do your FileResourceLoader by override Velocity's FileResourceLoader class,this class will concat WEB_APP_ROOT path and path item in velocity configration:

```
public class WebAppFileResourceLoader extends FileResourceLoader {
private Logger log= LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebAppFileResourceLoader.class);

@Override
public void init(ExtendedProperties configuration) {
    String webAppRootPath= (String) this.rsvc.getApplicationAttribute(WEB_APP_ROOT);
    if (webAppRootPath!=null) {
        Vector<String> pathsVector = configuration.getVector("path");
        Vector<String> tempVector = new Vector<String>(pathsVector.size());
        for (String path : pathsVector) {
            log.debug("path:{}", path);
            tempVector.add(webAppRootPath + File.separator + path);
        }
        configuration.clearProperty("path");
        for (String path : tempVector) {
            configuration.addProperty("path", path);
        }
    }
    super.init(configuration);
}
```

How to get WEB_APP_ROOT variable,we can set it when velocity engine init:

```
public class SpringVelocityEngineFactoryBean extends VelocityEngineFactory
    implements FactoryBean<VelocityEngine>, InitializingBean, ResourceLoaderAware,ServletContextAware {

private VelocityEngine velocityEngine;
private ServletContext servletContext;
private Logger log= LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringVelocityEngineFactoryBean.class);

@Override
protected VelocityEngine newVelocityEngine() throws IOException, VelocityException {
//inject servletContext to velocity runtime's applicationAttribute
    VelocityEngine velocityEngine= new VelocityEngine();
velocityEngine.setApplicationAttribute(ServletContext.class.getName(), this.servletContext);
    log.debug("webappRoot:{}",this.servletContext.getRealPath(""));
    velocityEngine.setApplicationAttribute(WEB_APP_ROOT,this.servletContext.getRealPath(""));
return velocityEngine;
}
....
```